# Couldn't make mysql connector j work

Tags: java, mysql, connector-j

I've set the classpath envoirenment but still get an error "Exception:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

Do you have any idea what might be wrong?

Here is my test code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class JdbcExample1 {

public static void main(String args[]) {
  Connection con = null;

  try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///test", "root", "secret");

    if(!con.isClosed())
      System.out.println("Successfully connected to MySQL server...");

  } catch(Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
  } finally {
    try {
      if(con != null)
        con.close();
      } catch(SQLException e) {}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Exception:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver*

Is most probably not the full error message. I guess it's a ClassNotFoundException and you simply do not have the MySQL JDBC driver as part of your classpath.

When running your program, you need to list the driver as well

`java -cp .;mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar JdbcExample1`
(This assumes JdbcExample1.class and the .jar file are in the current directory)

> *I've set the classpath envoirenment*

Setting the `CLASSPATH` environment variable is not necessary anymore (actually it never has been necessary). As a matter of fact it creates more problems than it solves.

Use the above syntax to supply the path to your driver and run your program

Answer (score 0):

As horse says, I'm pretty sure it's a 'ClassNotFoundException'.
To be sure add "e.printStackTrace();" in your catch-block.

Always best to get a stack trace.